# Button leaks when using ICommand

Tags: wpf

I am seeing a memory leak caused by the `CanExecuteChanged` eventhandler.

```
public class MyCommand : ICommand
{
  #region ICommand Members

  public virtual bool CanExecute(object parameter)
  {
     return true;
  }

  public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

  protected virtual void OnCanExecuteChanged(EventArgs e)
  {
     if (CanExecuteChanged != null)
        CanExecuteChanged(this, e);
  }

  public void Execute(object parameter)
  {

  }

 #endregion
}
```

When I run ANTS memory profiler it shows that the `CanExecuteChanged` eventhandler tied to the button has an `effectivevalueentry` in my viewmodel. My viewmodel is not being garbage collected.

XAML

```
<Button x:Uid="_editButton" x:Name="_editButton"
                            Tag="Edit"
                            Margin="1,1,1,1"
                            DockPanel.Dock="Left"
            Command="{Binding   Path=EditCommand}"
     CommandParameter="{Binding Path=SelectedItems, ElementName=SearchResultGrid}"
                            Content="{DynamicResource icoEdit1512Image}"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                            Visibility="{Binding Path=NewEditDeleteButtonVisibility}"
                            Localization.Attributes="Tag (Text Modifiable)">
                       <Button.Style>
                          <Style x:Uid="Style_2" TargetType="{x:Type Button}"
                                 BasedOn="{StaticResource dataGridToolBarButtonStyle}">
                             <Style.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger x:Uid="DataTrigger_1" Binding="{Binding ElementName=SearchResultGrid, 
                                                               Path=SelectedItem}"
                                             Value="{x:Null}">
                                   <Setter x:Uid="Setter_3" Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                             </Style.Triggers>
                          </Style>
                       </Button.Style>
                    </Button>
```

Comment: Memory leaks with events are a subscriber issue - what's subscribing to the event? Whatever it is, it's keeping a reference alive

Comment: Post the XAML where you're binding to this.

Comment: i have updated my post with xaml

Answer (score 0):

If you are just returning true always for `CanExecute` you can do the following:

```
public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged { add { } remove { } }
```

Then the handler won't be bound in the first place.

This, of course, won't work for when you actually want to be able to change `CanExecute`.  Solutions for that case can be found in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12945325/1245027).

Comment: See `OnCanExecuteChanged` from the question for the code to do this.  Though you should probably take a copy of the handler before checking for null, as the handler could become null between the check and the raise, which would throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was addressed in .NET 4.5. Please take a look at the [`CanExecuteChangedEventManager` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.canexecutechangedeventmanager.aspx) page on MSDN for more information on this.

From the linked page... this class

> Provides a WeakEventManager implementation so that you can use the "weak event listener" pattern to attach listeners for the CanExecuteChanged event.

You can find out more about Weak Event Patterns from the [Weak Event Patterns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970850.aspx) page on MSDN.